# PHP strlen() function abnormal behaviour in enterkey count

Tags: php, strlen

I am trying to find the count of following text in php using `strlen()` function,

```
<?php
    $a=" VII,C :06/11 ENG:TRANSLATION HUMAN BODY STRUCTURE
    TAM:FINISH CW &PULAVAR BOOK
    MAT:LEARN LN-1
    SOC:GEO:-1 CHOOSE,FILL UPS&MATCH
    SCI:MATTER&ITS NATURE.
    ";
?>
```

It returns 155 character length.

you can run the sample here http://codepad.org/qIJ0fBEj

and I removed the five enter spaces and run the below code,

```
<?php
$a=" VII,C :06/11 ENG:TRANSLATION HUMAN BODY STRUCTURETAM:FINISH CW &PULAVAR BOOKMAT:LEARN LN-1SOC:GEO:-1 CHOOSE,FILL UPS&MATCHSCI:MATTER&ITS NATURE.";
echo strlen($a);
?>
```

check the sample here http://codepad.org/JDFy6Y1t

It returns 145. How the 5 enter keys takes 10 count??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet this input came from a Windows computer. The new line is actually a carriage return (`\r`) *and* a new line character (`\n`). Thus *two* characters for each new line.

Comment: i want to get the actual count of enter key pressed. instead 155 i want 150.

Comment: Then remove all of the carriage returns before doing your count. You could even use `preg_match()`, too.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for John, carriage return is the issue. You can use `str_replace` to remove all the carriage returns from the string.

```
$a = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $a); // in windows
```